# Karma unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, karma-runner

I'm a total noob to unit testing javaScript, angularJS, and Karma. I've been able to write passing tests for the controllers, but now that I'm attempting to test the services, I'm getting the following error: `Unknown provider <- nProvider <- User` where User is the name of my service and from what I can tell, "n" is the $http dependency for that service (minified). Here is my UserService (TypeScript):

```
/// <reference path="../../lib/angular/angular.d.ts" />


module MyApp.Services{
    export class UserService{
        private _apiBase: string = "api/";

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService) {

        }

        getUser(userSearchParams: string): ng.IPromise{
            var deferred = this.$q.defer();
            this.$http.get(this._apiBase + "Users/" + userSearchParams).success((data) => {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(() => {
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my generic Services.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="../_all.d.ts" />

'use strict'

var mod = angular.module('MyApp.Services', []);

mod.factory('User', [<any>"$http", <any>"$q", function ($http, $q) {
    return new MyApp.Services.UserService($http, $q);
}]);
```

and finally, my test script:

```
'use strict';

describe('UserServiceTests', function () {

beforeEach(module('main'));  //this is my main angular module - set up in app.ts

it('should issue a GET request to api/Users/whatever when the search parameter is whatever', inject(function(User) {
    expect(2).toBe(2);
}));
```

})

I've created another test app with the same structure and I don't get the error seen above. I don't know what I'm missing. Let me know if there is anything more that I need to post in order to find the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: After much searching and reading, it appears that this is related to dependency injection [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) and [here](http://jaketrent.com/post/minimized-angularjs-dependency-injection/). Upon minification, the parameter names get changed, thus causing the error. As proof, if I delete the min files and re-run the tests, they pass.

The $inject function can be used to fix this, but I don't see how to do it when the controller is created as a class using TypeScript. I'm not sure if I can use the resolve property of $routeProvider.when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found [this](http://notebookheavy.com/2013/05/22/angularjs-and-typescript/) post, which allowed me to resolve the issue. By adding an "inject" property to my TypeScript classes (with the appropriate values in the array), Angular knows how to handle the DI. The only drawback I see is the potential for error in the order the dependencies are listed, or omission in the event a new dependency is added at a later time.